# Що означає фразеологізм “гнути коперчаки”?

Tags: фразеологізми, семантика

Почула від місцевих жителів Перемишлянщини (Львівська область) цікавий доволі фразеологізм **“гнути коперчаки”**.

Якщо ввести в контекст, матимемо приблизно так:

> ото він гне коперчаки!

Зацікавилась. У [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/koperchaky) та [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=43960&page=1391) не подають таких статей.

То що ж означає цей фразеологізм?

P. S.: в мене виникло припущення, що це може означати "**жартувати**", однак підтвердження ніде немає.

Comment: Цікаво, як так сталося, що Ви чули вираз, але не знаєте значення (НМД, тому, хто чув, спитати в носія — легше, ніж іншим здогадатися). Але запитання валідне. Може, хтось щось знає й підкаже.

Comment: @Sasha, коли транскрибувала із диктофона (не власноруч зафіксований) запис, почула вираз, тому ні запитати не можу, ні знайти інформації.

Answer (score 6):

У словниках польської мови: stroić koperczaki [strojity koperčaki] = фліртувати

гнути (pol. giąć) не існує

koperczaki arch. «umizgi, zaloty» dziś tylko we fraz.
Stroić, sadzić koperczaki, puszczać się, uderzać w koperczaki «umizgać się, zalecać się»

Але зі ["Свекруха: комедія в 3 діях" (1919)](https://archive.org/details/svekrukhakomedii00lopauoft), с. 18:

> Але я волїв би радше, панє мостердзею, до шановної мамунї копирчаки строїти. То вже і вік для мене відповіднїйший і стан поважнїйший, ну і мій цілий…

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Дякуємо, що приєдналися до спільноти.