# Що означає слово "коперчаки" у словосполученні "гнути коперчаки"?

Tags: значення-слів, іменники

У [попередньому дописі](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/4938/240) запитувала про значення фразеологізму ***“гнути коперчаки”***, однак ще окремо вирішила запитати про семантику слова **"коперчаки"**, оскільки ні [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/koperchaky), ні [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=43960&page=1391) не подають таких статей.

Answer (score 2):

koperczaki - з польської - це залицяння. Отже можу зробити припущення, що гнути коперчаки - це залицятися. Але я не є великий експерт із польської мови і такого виразу раніше не чув.

Comment: дякую, версія цікава!

Comment: Тут пишуть що зараз koperczaki означає залицяння, але у 18 сторіччі це означало робити різні жваві рухи - підскоки, перевертання тощо: https://sjp.pwn.pl/poradnia/haslo/koperczaki;1869.html

Comment: Додайте, будь ласка, джерела, щоб переклад був не просто вашею думкою, а був підкріплений чимось. Коли додасте - відповідайте мені - зніму мінус і поставлю плюс.